# Stop form submission and keep form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added a validation check on my form submission but problem is that it stopped the form from being submitted but it also reset my whole form. Kindly let me know how can i on `return false` also stop the form submission and stop resetting the whole form. Thanks

```
function error()
{
   if (!$("#form1 input[name='radio']:checked").val()) {
     alert('Error: Please select any check box!');
     return false;
   }
   else {
     //alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
   }
}

<form name="form1" id="form1">
  <input name="Name" type="text" id="name" size="70" />
  <input name="Age" type="text" id="age" size="70" />
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="A18" value="18" />
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="A19" value="19" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="error();" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the form's `submit` event with your validation function, and return `false`:

```
$("#form1").submit(error);
```

Returning false from your `submit` handler will cancel the form submission, and the current state of the form's elements will be maintained.

Comment: This would be a good idea, though handling the "click" on the "submit" button can work, at least for the button interactions.

Comment: @Pointy What if they press "return" on any other input field? I seldom submit a from by actually clicking the button.

Comment: the code you mentioned will trigger the (`.submit(error)`) error function?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do more than just return `false` from the function:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return error();" />
```

Because the value of the "onclick" attribute is essentially used as the body of the *actual* handler function, it needs its own `return` statement.

*edit* — meagar's answer is a good idea - it would be wise to handle the "submit" event on the form instead of the "click" event on the button. If you set up the event handler via jQuery as in his example, the `return` in the "error" function is all you need.

Comment: i think his answer is more good practice so i should make it work that way right?

Comment: @user2304394 well yes, the form "submit" event is sort-of a catch-all for everything that can make the form be submitted, especially when you set it up via jQuery.  Also, if you're using jQuery, it's good to use it for managing event handlers instead of the old-fashioned "onclick" etc in the HTML.